# Convert Alphanumeric (Base36) to int (Base10) and Viceversa

Tags: php, converters, radix

I have this string "AUB9789LJLKA89". I need to convert it to an int, and later I need to be able to convert it back to string.

In order to do this I found in PHP "base_convert", but when I convert "AUB9789LJLKA89" to Base10 I get the number: 1849450200354407248260, and if I convert that number to Base36 back I get "AUB9789LJLKWCC". Very different from "AUB9789LJLKA89".

```
base_convert("AUB9789LJLKA89", 36, 10); //I get 1849450200354407248260
base_convert(1849450200354407248260, 10, 36); //I get AUB9789LJLKWCC
```

How can I fix this? Or which other way can I use to convert an alphanumeric to an int way and back.

Comment: Might be because of the warning in the PHP docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php _(base_convert() may lose precision on large numbers due to properties related to the internal "double" or "float" type used)._

Comment: Also, I think you may be dealing with numbers larger than what PHP can handle. 1849450200354407248260 is 3 digits longer than PHP_INT_MAX of 9223372036854775807.  You may need to use something like GMP, https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php, the first example is for converting bases.

Answer (score 0):

I found this function for converting bases written by a contributor at the [php doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) page, try it and see if it gives you the result you want.

```
function convBase($numberInput, $fromBaseInput, $toBaseInput)
{
    if ($fromBaseInput == $toBaseInput) {
        return $numberInput;
    }

    $fromBase = str_split($fromBaseInput, 1);
    $toBase = str_split($toBaseInput, 1);
    $number = str_split($numberInput, 1);
    $fromLen = strlen($fromBaseInput);
    $toLen = strlen($toBaseInput);
    $numberLen = strlen($numberInput);
    $retval = '';
    if ($toBaseInput == '0123456789') {
        $retval = 0;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $numberLen; $i++) {
            $retval = bcadd($retval, bcmul(array_search($number[$i - 1], $fromBase), bcpow($fromLen, $numberLen - $i)));
        }

        return $retval;
    }
    if ($fromBaseInput != '0123456789') {
        $base10 = convBase($numberInput, $fromBaseInput, '0123456789');
    } else {
        $base10 = $numberInput;
    }

    if ($base10 < strlen($toBaseInput)) {
        return $toBase[$base10];
    }

    while ($base10 != '0') {
        $retval = $toBase[bcmod($base10, $toLen)] . $retval;
        $base10 = bcdiv($base10, $toLen, 0);
    }
    return $retval;
}

$b36 = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$b10 = '0123456789';
$b5 = '01234';
$b2 = '01';

$con = convBase('AUB9789LJLKA89', $b36, $b10); // 1849450200354407014857
$con = convBase('1849450200354407014857', $b10, $b36); // AUB9789LJLKA89
```